# insert javascript widget inside wordpress text-widged

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, widget

I'd like to place a java-script snippet inside the text-widget and place this into the right-sidebar.

I'm using wordpress 3.6.1 with theme-horse-attitude, I'm trying this with "HTML Javascript Adder" but getting an Error.

The code I'd like to place is this:

```
<div id="meinWettbewerb1">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var wettbewerb1 = new fussballdeAPI();
    wettbewerb1.setzeWettbewerb('01HLJMM2Q4000000VV0AG812VS2HNECA-G');
    wettbewerb1.setzeMandant('34');
    wettbewerb1.zeigeBegegnungen('meinWettbewerb1');
</script>
```

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/allow-javascript-in-text-widgets/

Comment: allow-javascript-in-text-widgets is not working in wordpress 3.6.1 / there is no real error, but its not working. in the tutorial video they are using iframe instead the code-syntax like above, but i don't get an auto-generated iframe-code and do not know how to translate it.